# Replacing strings in multiple text files using regular expressions on vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking to build a simple text string replacement tool using visual studio 2015 community tool, which will do the below replacements on all *.txt files whose path is given in a textbox:

```
Find: \<figure (\d+)\>
Replace: <a href id="fig\1">figure \1</a>

Find: \<table (\d+)\>
Replace: <a href id="tab\1">table \1</a>

Find: \<section (\d+)\>
Replace: <a href id="sec\1">section \1</a>
```

I have coded a little portion of the programme but struggling to complete it. I'm completely new in programming and in visual basic is well. Can anyone help complete this programme

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If FBD.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            TextBox1.Text = FBD.SelectedPath
        End If
    End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim targetDirectory As String
    targetDirectory = TextBox1.Text
    Dim Files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory, "*.txt")
    For Each file In Files
        Dim FileInfo As New FileInfo(file)
        Dim FileLocation As String = FileInfo.FullName
        Dim input As String = file.ReadAllLines(FileLocation)
        Dim pattern1 As String = "\<figure (\d+)\>"
        Dim pattern2 As String = "\<table (\d+)\>"
        Dim pattern3 As String = "\<section (\d+)\>"
        Dim rep1 As String = "<a href id= \""fig\1\"" > figure \1</a>"
        Dim rep2 As String = "<a href id= \""tab\1\"" > table \1</a>"
        Dim rep3 As String = "<a href id= \""sec\1\"" > section \1</a>"
        Dim rgx1 As New Regex(pattern1)
        Dim rgx2 As New Regex(pattern2)
        Dim rgx3 As New Regex(pattern3)
        Dim result1 As String = rgx1.Replace(input, rep1)
        Dim result2 As String = rgx2.Replace(result1, rep2)
        Dim result3 As String = rgx3.Replace(result2, rep3)
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

The errors I'm getting are given below

```
Error   BC30456 'ReadAllLines' is not a member of 'String'
```

Answer (score 2):

For the replace button, once you have the link to the folder directory, you need to read in all files that say "*.txt". The below line does this

```
targetDirectory = TextBox1.text
Dim txtFilesArray As String() = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory,"*.txt")
```

You can then loop through this array and do your replace logic.

```
    For each txtFile in txtFilesArray
        'here we grab the files information as we need the files directory
        Dim FileInfo As New FileInfo(txtFile)
        Dim FileLocation As String = FileInfo.FullName
        Dim input() as string = File.ReadAllLines(FileLocation)
        'now you have read in your text file you can edit each file as it goes through the loop
        'you can now use your regex here to edit each file, 
        'then once done editing the file, dont forget to write back to your file or it wont save
        'you will need to loop through the input array now to change the line
       For x as integer = 0 to (input.length - 1)
         Dim pattern1 As String = "\<figure (\d+)\>"
         Dim pattern2 As String = "\<table (\d+)\>"
         Dim pattern3 As String = "\<section (\d+)\>"
         Dim rep1 As String = "<a href id= \""fig\1\"" > figure \1</a>"
         Dim rep2 As String = "<a href id= \""tab\1\"" > table \1</a>"
         Dim rep3 As String = "<a href id= \""sec\1\"" > section \1</a>"
         Dim rgx1 As New Regex(pattern1)
         Dim rgx2 As New Regex(pattern2)
         Dim rgx3 As New Regex(pattern3)
         Dim result1 As String = rgx1.Replace(input(x), rep1)
         Dim result2 As String = rgx2.Replace(result1, rep2)
         Dim result3 As String = rgx3.Replace(result2, rep3)
         input(x) = result3
       Next
      'now you can write your corrected file back to the file
      File.WriteAllLines(FileLocation, input)
    Next

  MsgBox("process complete")
```

Comment: Dear Cal-cium, thank you for your reply, could you please elaborate a little about how can I modify the replacement codes
    Dim result1 As String = rgx1.Replace(input, rep1)
     inside 
"For each file in Files"
     ????

as the replace method requires "input" and "replacement". So how do I modify the "input" part

Comment: Are you trying to edit the contents of each of these files?

Comment: yes. The contents of each file will be replace according to the regular expression replaces given.

Comment: Well inside each "for each file in Files" loop, you need to read in the text file and edit it. You already have your list of files "Files" and the loop is going through each file "file". Also check updated answer on how

Comment: I have updated my coding according to your instructions but it is showing some errors, can you help me on this. Please check my updated question.

Comment: Shouldn't your regex replace be `Dim result1 As String = rgx1.Replace(input, rep1)`?  i think it should be input not Files

Comment: Thinking maybe something like this `Dim result1 As String = rgx1.Replace(input, rep1)
        Dim result2 As String = rgx2.Replace(result1, rep2)
        Dim result3 As String = rgx3.Replace(result3, rep3)`  Then you write result3 back to the file, or you thinking of doing something different?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It should be `Dim result1 As String = rgx1.Replace(input, rep1) Dim result2 As String = rgx2.Replace(result1, rep2) Dim result3 As String = rgx3.Replace(result3, rep3)`
But still there is the error `BC30456 'ReadAllLines' is not a member of 'String'.`
Also how do I write result3 back to the file?

Comment: That was my bad, it should have been `Dim input() as String = File.ReadAllLines(FileLocation)` as ReadAllLines returns an array of strings. I forgot about that. Check updated answer.

Comment: Now it shows 2 errors
`Error BC30456 'ReadAllLines' is not a member of 'String'.
Error BC30456 'WriteAllLines' is not a member of 'String'.
`

Comment: i figured it out, it was due to this bit of code `For Each file In Files`. I shouldn't have said to use file for the name of a variable, that was bad naming. I updated answer. and changed it to `For each txtFile in Files`. When trying to use ReadAllLines and WriteAllLines it was trying to do this on the file varaible rather than system.io.File. This is a good reason why we should name variables sensibly. My bad, sorry about that.

Comment: I've tested this on my computer and it should all be working now :)

Comment: One last question, where do I put `MsgBox.show("process complete")` message to show after all the replaces are done? And what exactly does the For loop `For x As Integer = 0 To (input.Length - 1)` does

Comment: `MsgBox.show("process complete")` is put at the end of the code. Check updated answer. The For Loop `For x As Integer = 0 To (input.Length - 1)`  loops through the array input. As we made input an array, we have to loop through this as well so your regex can edit it.

Comment: I've tried putting `MsgBox.show("process complete")` at the position mentioned by you but it shows an error `Error BC30455 Argument not specified for parameter 'Prompt' of 'Public Function MsgBox(Prompt As Object, [Buttons As MsgBoxStyle = ApplicationModal], [Title As Object = Nothing]) As MsgBoxResult'.`

Comment: That's probably because it should be `MsgBox("process complete")`  or `MessageBox.Show("process complete")`. You have kind of mixed the 2 up.

Comment: Also, how do I use a progressbar in this programme?

Comment: I think that requires a new question entirely. Research into progress bars and if still stuck ask a new question on stack overflow. If this answer answered your question, please mark as answered.

Comment: @TamalBanerjee Although Don_B answered your latest question in this comment thread, it doesn't really answer your original question. Other people might look at this for their own similar problems.

Answer (score -2):

@Tamal Banerjee, try this for progress bar, put the below code after the last `Next` in the coding

```
Next
ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
ProgressBar1.Value = 100
MessageBox.Show("Process complete")
End Sub
```

I'm not sure whether this is the write way to do it, but it worked when tried this on my computer with your coding :)

Comment: On mine the messagebox appears while the progress bar is still incrementing

Comment: Way i did it was to put this before the for each loop `ProgressBar1.Maximum = txtFilesArray.Count` and then put this this before the last next `ProgressBar1.Increment(1)  Refresh() Thread.Sleep(100)`  and finally put this before the messagebox `Thread.Sleep(400)
        MsgBox("Process complete")`

Comment: Is `ProgressBar1.Increment(1) Refresh() Thread.Sleep(100)` is in one line? I put it like `ProgressBar1.Increment(1)` , `Refresh()` and `Thread.Sleep(100)` in three lines, but it shows an error `Error BC30451 'Thread' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.`

Comment: no sorry, each is on a separate line. They are 3 separate bits of code

Comment: You need to make sure you have `Imports System.Threading` in the program

Comment: Could you please explain how the coding works? I'm a beginner in coding so it will be helpful if I can understand how the coding works.

Comment: Well `ProgressBar1.Maximum = txtFilesArray.Count` sets the maximum the progress bar can be. So for how many files there are in the array, when incremented it can go up equally for each file it completes. `ProgressBar1.Increment(1)` makes the progressbar go up by 1. So putting this part at the end of completing 1 file is most logical. `Refresh()` just refreshes the form, allowing the progressbar to show its  implementing. `Me.Refresh()` is basically what it is, but you don't need to put `Me.` as it recognizes it. `ProgressBar1.refresh()` would have also worked.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(100)` is basically suspending the current thread for a specific amount of time. I believe it works in milliseconds. So this just allows the program to slow down in order to show the progressbar working and by doing it this way, each time it goes up the program has completed one of the files. Good practice you can do, is to change the `thread.sleep()` times around and see how it changes the program. It basically how figured out how much time to use, by trial and error.

Comment: Though in theory you could use a `thread.sleep()` in your code before the msgbox and the progressbar would finish before the msgbox appears but the progressbar wouldn't represent when it actually finished a file when it increments.